# vim :make to compile and run C code if it's a success

Tags: c, vim, g++

to compile C programs and run it, I use ":make" but I would like to run the compiled program too if the compile is a success.

I wrote

```
au FileType c setlocal makeprg=g++\ %\ \&\&\ ./a.out
```

in vimrc, that works, but I have a vim error when there's some mistakes in my code, so vim don't put the cursor on the good line.
I get this error :

> E40: Can't open errorfile
>   /tmp/vEtUQQ2/0

Is there a workaround, a fix or another way to achieve this ?

Comment: I have the same problem, does anyone know why this error happens?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a way with pure vim to do it, but it is a bit of annoying.

Using QuickFixCmdPost(Autocmd Event) to check if there is building error after ':make' ran.
And if there are no errors, run the newly compiled program.

```
autocmd QuickfixCmdPost make call AfterMakeC()
function! AfterMakeC()
    " No any error after make
    if len(getqflist()) == 0
        !./a.out
    endif
    " :~)
endfunction
```

You may want to put the script under  namespace in **compiler plugin**

Comment: Thanks Mike Lue, seems really what I'm looking for, but I don't get how to do it. 
I have had tested that, but that doesn't work :
 au FileType c setlocal makeprg=g++\ %;

 au QuickfixCmdPost c ./a.out

Comment: @sputnick The autocmd should be run before you run `:make`, possibly in your .vimrc or other file automatically loaded on vim start.  Then the autocmd will fire after the :make command runs but before the error list is displayed.

Comment: Not exactly right, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552933/vim-count-determine-number-of-errors-in-quickfix#comment27147681_1553008) comment.

Answer (score 10):

You could create a target in your makefile to run the program (say 'run'):

```
.PHONY : run
run : $(PROG) # assuming $(PROG) is the name of your program
    ./$(PROG)
```

...and then in vim you would do:

```
:make run
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, but I don't use Makefile for the small developments.